# Executing AWS-CLI commands on AWS lambda (Node.JS runtime)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

My Node.JS api needs the AWS-CLI in order to function. As the Lambda runtime does not have this installed out of the box, I was wondering if there was a way to install it.

I am using the child_process library (spawnSync in particular) to send this command. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't just use aws-sdk?

Comment: I am taking an advantage of a module which uses the aws-cli... In order to use the sdk I would have to rewrite the entire module (its quite large).

Comment: I would just use a pre-configured Lambda layer, like this one: https://github.com/CM-Kajiwara/awscli-lambda-layer or this https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lambda-layer-awscli